# How to force the repository method that return an object to make the database call from the action method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following model repository method:

```
public SystemInformation GetSystemInfo(int pagesize) 
{
    SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
    {
        CustomCount = tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => a.Quantity),
        TechnologyAudit = AllIncludingTechnologyAudit("", null, auditinfo => auditinfo.Technology, auditinfo2 => auditinfo2.TechnologyType, auditinfo3 => auditinfo3.AuditAction)
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.ID)
            .Take(pagesize),
        AdminAudit = AllIncludingAdminAudit("", auditinfo => auditinfo.SecurityTaskType, auditinfo2 => auditinfo2.AuditAction)
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.ID)
            .Take(pagesize),
        LatestTechnology = LatestTechnology()
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.TechnologyID)
            .Take(pagesize)
    };

    return s;
}
```

And I am calling this method from my action method as:

```
public ViewResult SystemInfo()
{
    return View(repository.GetSystemInfo(100));
}
```

But since the repository method returns single object of type `SystemInformation` I am unable to write a `.Tolist()` inside my action method to force the database query to be send to the DB from my action method instead of being issued from my view. So my question is how I can force the `repository.GetSystemInfo(100)` call to initiate the DB call?

Comment: You should really reformat that code; it's a nightmare to read, with all of that horizontal scrolling and inconsistent indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two real options here.  The first is, if you know that you'll never want to defer execution of each of those properties within `SystemInformation` then you can alter the `GetSystemInfo` method to add a `ToList` to each of the queries, so they aren't deferred.

Another option would be to have two methods, one that defers execution and one that doesn't, if you sometimes want to rely on the deferred execution.

The only way to materialize the queries after being given one from the method that you have is to pull out each of the queries, materialze them into a collection, and then set the properties of that object (or create a new one) based on those in memory collections.

Comment: so you mean i should add three .tolist() to the ;TechnologyAudit & AdminAudit  & LatestTechnology ?

Comment: @johnG Assuming you aren't relying on using deferred execution in other places when calling this method; yes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is caching from entity framework. If you need to force a query, you can establish a new connection. If this is the ideal, you may look at the lifetime of your context. if you find yourself frequently needing this behavior, look at changing the unit of work or when/where you establish a database connection.

As an aside, your connection should only persist for as long as you need it. You shouldn't have the connection open (and dormant) for long periods of time. by closing the connection you're not only saving a connection on the database, but also freeing up resources locally. Additionally, you're ensuring that every new connection is working with the most recent version of data (instead of what *it* perceives it the latest version).